# Chromecast VTT not showing

Tags: chromecast, captions, vtt

I am creating a Chromecast app that streams video and uses out of stream VTT captions. I have successfully managed to load TTML but I require to load VTT also for this I have the following code

```
this.player.enableCaptions(true, 'vtt', 'http://some_file.vtt');
```

this fails within the MediaPlayer.js with tyhe following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parse' of null
```

This looks to be in the code to load the individual cues has anyone come across this problem?

Comment: vtt should have been webvtt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.player.enableCaptions(true, 'vtt', 'http://some_file.vtt');
```

should be

```
this.player.enableCaptions(true, 'webvtt', 'http://some_file.vtt');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the (text/audio) track(s) information to your MediaInfo and then set the active track. Take a look at this [guide](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/chrome_sender#tracks). Also be aware that having tracks, even when your media is mp4, would require CORS.